# Aggregation by nested field after filter

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm triying to get all the logs around a expecific geopoint, and group them by a subfield (context.id) but I'm having problems. I tried the nested aggregation, etc.. but I'm having no luck. I'm using the PHP library so I wrote the query as a php array. All is working until addign the aggregation query.

The exception throw is :

```
illegal_state_exception: Field data loading is forbidden on [context.id]


$params = [
        'index' => 'logstash-*',
        'type'  => 'INFO',
        'body'  => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    "must"   => [
                        ["term" => ["tags" => "producer"]],
                        ["term" => ["tags" => "statistics"]],
                        ["term" => ["message" => "view"]],
                    ],
                    "filter" => [
                        "geo_distance" => [
                            "distance"       => "10km",
                            "distance_type"  => "plane",
                            "geoip.location" => [
                                "lat" => 40.4326058,
                                "lon" => -3.6996032
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "aggs"  => [
                "context" => [
                    "nested" => [
                        "path" => "context"
                    ],
                    "aggs"   => [
                        "group_by_id" => [
                            "terms" => ["field" => "context.id"]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ];
```

Can someone point me to the right query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem here was the field. It was a indexed field I need to use the "context.id.raw" field instead.